# Magento PHP setting on server

Tags: php

I am running Magento 1.9.2.0 and  Plesk server and the PHP handler is 5.3.3 and everything is working. I want to know if I an change the PHP settings on my server to 5.4 and if I will make any difference or problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has supported php 5.4 since Magento 1.6 so yes you can update your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your php to `> 5.3` version. This will make sure your system runs smoothly and lot of php bug are fixed than earlier version.

Have a look here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

**Minimum PHP version required by Magento 1.9.2.0 is 5.4.**